# C++ Array of Pointers not assignable

Tags: c++

I need to create 2 arrays, each with 4 elements.  One array contains four `int` values gotten from the user, and the other array contains pointers to the elements of the first array.  I keep getting the following error:

> array type 'int *[4]' is not assignable

on this line:

```
my_ptrs = &my_ints;
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int my_ints[4];
    int *my_ptrs[4];
    float temp;
    int num;

    for (int x=0; x< 4; x++)
    {
        cout << "Enter Integer:" << endl;
        cin >> num;
        my_ints[x] = num;
    }

    my_ptrs = &my_ints;

    for(int k=0; k<=3; k++)
    {
        for(int j=k+1; j<=3; j++)
        {
            if(my_ptrs[k]>my_ptrs[j])
            {
                temp=*my_ptrs[k];
                my_ptrs[k]=my_ptrs[j];
                *my_ptrs[j]=temp;
            }
        }
        cout << my_ptrs[k] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apparent intent is to have each pointer in `my_ptrs` to point to the corresponding value in `my_ints`.

I'm afraid there are no shortcuts here, using a single assignment. You have to do it the hard way:

```
for (int i=0; i<4; ++i)
     my_ptrs[i]=&my_ints[i];
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: what is incorrect about my last for loop where i want to print the my_ptrs array in ascending order

Comment: You either have to swap the values the pointers are pointing to, or swap the pointers itself. That for loop is attempting to do half of one and half of the other. That's not going to work. The middle assignment should probably be `*my_ptrs[k]=*my_ptrs[j];` And `temp` should be an `int`. It makes absolutely no sense, whatsoever, for `temp` to be a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a pointer-to-an-array to an array variable, like you are trying to do.  But what you can do instead is either:

- initialize the second array in its declaration directly:

  ```
  int my_ints[4];
  int* my_ptrs[4] = {&my_ints[0], &my_ints[1], &my_ints[2], &my_ints[3]};
  ```
- populate the array in a separate loop:

  ```
  int my_ints[4];
  int* my_ptrs[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
      my_ptrs[i] = &my_ints[i];
  ```

That being said, based on what you are *trying* to do ("*i want to print the `my_ptrs` array in ascending order*"), you could just get rid of the second array altogether and use the [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) algorithm instead:

> Sorts the elements in the range [first, last) in ascending order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int my_ints[4];

    for (int x = 0; x < 4; ++x)
    {
        cout << "Enter Integer:" << endl;
        cin >> my_ints[x];
    }

    std::sort(my_ints, my_ints+4);

    for(int k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
        cout << my_ints[k] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```